# Robbers in a standoff

Tags: mathematics

A group of robbers are in a standoff. Each robber has two guns that they must point at two other distinct robbers. What is the minimum number of robbers in the standoff so that a situation is possible where no two robbers are mutually shooting at one another?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling, take our [tour]! Could you please provide [proper attribution](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7259/proper-attribution-for-non-original-puzzles-a-guide) for this question?

Comment: Seems like the last clause should be "where no two robbers are mutually *pointing* at one another".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There must be at least

> 5 robbers.

This is because

> in order to be able to have at most one gun per robber pair, there must be at least as many pairs as there are guns.
>  This means $2n \leq \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$, which solves to $5 \leq n$.

For completeness, since everyone insists:

> When there are 5 robbers, you can choose any robber and partition the other 4 into two pairs: one pair the robber points at, and the other pair points at the robber. There is, up to permutation of the robbers, only one way to do this: place the robbers in a circle and partition according to which side of the robber the other robbers are on as in @cap's solution.

Comment: You type faster than me.  And you jax'd it!

Comment: That final inequality is in the wrong direction. I also think that even though you've established a lower bound, you haven't shown that it is actually possible with that minimum number of robbers.

Comment: Yea, a good answer will need to construct the situation for n=5, like cap's answer does

Answer (score 9):

We need at least

> 5 robbers.
>  Each robber has 2 people pointing a gun at him and he needs 2 robbers to point his guns at for a total of at least 5. Imagine they all stand in a circle and each robber points his left gun at the guy to his left and his right gun at the next guy to the left.
>  [image]

Comment: I feel like this could use more justification that this is the minimum. While you've shown a valid configuration for the proposed minimum number of robbers, you've only demonstrated that this approach doesn't work for a lower number, not that there is no approach for a lower number

Comment: @ StephenTG good point, I'll make it more explicit.

Answer (score 5):

Each Robber must choose 2 paths, for 2n used paths.

Once a path is chosen, it is excluded in the reverse direction. That is, A->B precludes B->A.

So the number of paths available is nC2, [Combination formula] or the number of ways we can choose 2 people.

This formula simplifies to n(n-1)/2.

> For n = 3, we need 6 paths, and there are 3 available. [No good]
>  For n = 4, we need 8 paths, and there are 6 available. [No good]
>  For n = 5, we need 10 paths and there are 10 available. [Good!]

The paths need grows linearly, and the paths available grows quadratically, so there will always be more paths available than needed for larger values of n.

Answer (score 0):

> Let's start with the first robber ($R_1$, $n=1$) and work up. She needs $+2$ targets ($n=3$). $R_2$ and $R_3$ can't point at $R_1$, and at least one of them can't point at the other, so at a minimum $+2$ more targets must exist ($n=5$).

We can check whether this is a valid solution by:

> having each robber $R_n$ aim at the next two and verifying that $R_n$ is in turn targeted exactly twice: $$R_1 => R_2, R_3$$ $$R_2 => R_3, R_4$$ $$R_3 => R_4, R_5$$ $$R_4 => R_5, R_1$$ $$R_5 => R_1, R_2$$

Comment: You claim that R2 and R3 can't point at each other, and then post a solution where R2 points at R3 - it is certainly true that *both* of them can't aim at each other, and this is sufficient for your bound, but your proof as written is flawed.

Comment: @AxiomaticSystem ha good catch I misworded that, justification updated.